# how to write a subquery which is using outer tables for calculation in select query, Can we write this in tuned manner

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

3 tables Product,sales, discount.

```
create table Product (Pid Varchar2(15),Productname Varchar2(50),PriceofSingle Number(10));
Create table Disc_product(pid varchar2(15),Qty number,disc_percent number);
create table sales(salesid number(20),Pid varchar2(15),productname varchar2(40) ,qty number(10));
```

want to retrieve the details of the product . if products are purchased in more than in quantity provided in disc_product table , then discount percentage is applicable else no.

i have written the query its working fine .....buts its very messy....
i want is there any other way to implement the same ..

```
Select  s.salesid,s.pid,p.Productname,s.qty ,
    (NVL((select disc_percent from disc_product where pid = s.pid and qty <s.qty),1)) as disc, 
    ((p.priceofsingle * s.qty ) * (NVL((select disc_percent from disc_product where pid = s.pid and qty <s.qty),1) )) as T_price** 
from sales s left join product p on S.pid = p.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a qtymin and qtymax to your Disc_product table. You can then perform a LEFT JOIN to match the discount between the values. Otherwise, you will be showing duplicate lines with all of the discount tiers.

```
SELECT  
s.salesid,
s.pid,
p.productname,
s.qty,
NVL(d.disc_percent,1), 
p.priceofsingle * s.qty * NVL(d.disc_percent,1) as T_price
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN Product p
ON s.pid = p.pid
LEFT JOIN Disc_Product d
ON s.pid = d.pid AND s.qty >= d.qtymin AND s.qty < d.qtymax;
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  In Discount table structure , we have only one column of qty.